# SQL division gives answer only for the last row

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to calculate `efficiency` in my sql code which requires division of 2 variables `vehicle_dispatched` and `available_cars` but it returns a same answer for the whole column. Here is my sql code:

```
SELECT *,@vehicles_dispatched:=COUNT(DISTINCT v.vehicle_id) AS vehicles_dispatched,
@available_cars:=(SELECT COUNT(vehicle_id) FROM vehicles WHERE company_id=1) AS available_cars,
FORMAT(@vehicles_dispatched / @available_cars,2) AS efficiency
FROM driver_attendance da 
LEFT JOIN vehicles v ON v.vehicle_id=da.vehicle_id
LEFT JOIN collection co ON co.driver_attendance_id=da.driver_attendance_id
LEFT JOIN collectible cb ON cb.collectible_id = co.collectible_id
WHERE company_id=1 GROUP BY attendance_date DESC
```

Sample output:

```
vehicles_dispatched available_cars efficiency
        5                 7          0.14
        3                 7          0.14
        6                 7          0.14
        1                 7          0.14
```

Problem is that there are same answers for the whole column instead of performing divisions for each row.

here is the updated query which gives my desired output, all thanks to @Ravinder.

```
SELECT *,FORMAT( vehicle_dispatched /  available_cars, 2 ) AS efficiency
 FROM(
  SELECT da.*, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN attendance_status = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_cars_collectible,
    SUM(boundary_payment)+SUM(deficit_payment) AS total_daily_collection,
    ((SUM(boundary_due)+SUM(boundary_deficit)) - (SUM(boundary_payment)+SUM(deficit_payment))) AS total_short,
    @cars_in_maintenance:=(SELECT SUM(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN vehicle_on_duty=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS cars_under_maintenance FROM vehicles WHERE company_id=84) AS cars_in_maintenance,
    @vehicle_dispatched:=COUNT(DISTINCT v.vehicle_id) AS vehicle_dispatched,
    @available_cars:=(SELECT COUNT(vehicle_id) FROM vehicles WHERE company_id=84) AS available_cars
    FROM driver_attendance da 
    LEFT JOIN vehicles    v  ON v.vehicle_id            = da.vehicle_id 
    LEFT JOIN collection  co ON co.driver_attendance_id = da.driver_attendance_id 
    LEFT JOIN collectible cb ON cb.collectible_id       = co.collectible_id 
   WHERE v.company_id = 84
   GROUP BY da.attendance_date DESC
 ) AS vehicles_attended
```

Comment: In `vehicles` table, is `vehicle_id` a primary key or a foreign key? Because, if `primary`, then `distinct vehicle_id` is not required.

Comment: its a primary key, but when there are instances that it is repeated when `LEFT JOIN` is used with `driver_attendance`, hence I used `DISTINCT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When aggregate functions like `count`, `max`, etc are used with user defined variables, resulting behaviour is not known. I could not find documentation on that.

A similar question is raised by me some time back on SO:
[*... When a similar statement was executed with aggregate functions like count, sum, group by, the results pattern was entirely different .... Example on SQL Fiddle ...*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22388419/767881)

On your query, you can first calculate counts of various values and then calculate `efficiency` in an outer query.

```
select vehicles_dispatched, available_cars
     , format( vehicles_dispatched /  available_cars, 2 ) as efficiency
 from(
  select da.*, count( distinct v.vehicle_id ) as vehicles_dispatched
       , count( v.vehicle_id ) as available_cars
    from driver_attendance     da 
    left join vehicles    v  on v.vehicle_id            = da.vehicle_id 
    left join collection  co on co.driver_attendance_id = da.driver_attendance_id 
    left join collectible cb on cb.collectible_id       = co.collectible_id 
   where v.company_id = 1
   group by da.attendance_date desc;
 ) as vehicles_attended
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I made a few tweaks upon integrating it with my code but this really helped a lot. cheers!

Comment: Post your updated query that fetched proper result. That would help others as well.

Comment: okay, i'll just add it to my question above because its too long to be displayed as a comment.