# MySQL Query result fields using SQL @variable are null

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I have a MySQL Statement which is using MySQL Variables like "@StepWidth" and variables that are used in IF-Statements.

The Query work fine in MySQL Workbench but when using with PHP and mysqli_query the field with the variables came back empty (null).

Idea is, to round the date that is stored in the DB round up to the next minute, hour, or day depending on the give step width value that is set by the PHP script and group the result by the unix_timestamp that is calculated with this to get a small result for use this later in a chart.

The Query

```
SELECT
    @stepWidth:=900 as StepWidth,
    task_template.puid,
    task_template.ptemlate_name AS series_name,
    round(avg(job.JOB_DURATION)) as value,
    job.pcreation_date,
case
    WHEN @stepWidth < 3600 THEN @RoundedCreationDate:=from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(job.pcreation_date) - MOD(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(job.pcreation_date), @stepWidth), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s")
    WHEN @stepWidth >= 3600 AND @stepWidth < 86400 THEN    @RoundedCreationDate:=DATE_ADD( DATE_FORMAT(job.pcreation_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00"), INTERVAL IF(MINUTE(job.pcreation_date) < 30, 0, 1) HOUR
)
    WHEN @stepWidth >= 86400 then @RoundedCreationDate:=DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD( DATE_FORMAT(job.pcreation_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00"), INTERVAL IF(HOUR(job.pcreation_date) < 12, 0, 1) DAY ),"%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00" )
END AS RoundedCreationDate,
round(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(@RoundedCreationDate)) as start
FROM ( select @start := 0, @RoundedCreationDate := "1990-01-01" ) as Sqlvars, job 
    INNER JOIN task_template ON task_template.puid = job.rprocess_templateu
WHERE job.pcreation_date BETWEEN "2013-10-02 00:00:00" AND "2013-10-02 23:59:59"
GROUP BY task_template.puid,
task_template.ptemlate_name,"start"
ORDER BY task_template.ptemlate_name, "start";
```

I have also tried to write the result to a temporary table but this brings the same result.
I hope somebody can help me.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Behaviour of session variables when used with aggregate functions is not predictable. Alternatively, first prepare the results using session variables and then apply aggregates on those results. Also [***read one of my question on so***](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22388419/).

Comment: Is it possible that it works in Workbench just because you're reusing the same connection and your variables already have a value from previous attempts?

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be mixing a few things. For example you initialise @stepWidth in the SELECT statement while other variables are initialised in a sub query.

Further you have mixed up implicit and explicit join syntax. A result of this is that implicit joins have a lower precedence, and this can cause problems.

Try switching to an explicit CROSS JOIN and initialise the variables in one place:-

```
SELECT
    @stepWidth AS StepWidth,
    task_template.puid,
    task_template.ptemlate_name AS series_name,
    ROUND(AVG(job.JOB_DURATION)) AS value,
    job.pcreation_date,
    case
        WHEN @stepWidth < 3600 
            THEN @RoundedCreationDate:=from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(job.pcreation_date) - MOD(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(job.pcreation_date), @stepWidth), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s")
        WHEN @stepWidth >= 3600 AND @stepWidth < 86400 
            THEN    @RoundedCreationDate:=DATE_ADD( DATE_FORMAT(job.pcreation_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00"), INTERVAL IF(MINUTE(job.pcreation_date) < 30, 0, 1) HOUR)
        WHEN @stepWidth >= 86400 then @RoundedCreationDate:=DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD( DATE_FORMAT(job.pcreation_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00"), INTERVAL IF(HOUR(job.pcreation_date) < 12, 0, 1) DAY ),"%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00" )
    END AS RoundedCreationDate,
    ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(@RoundedCreationDate)) AS start
FROM job 
INNER JOIN task_template ON task_template.puid = job.rprocess_templateu
CROSS JOIN
( 
    select @start := 0, @RoundedCreationDate := "1990-01-01", @stepWidth := 900 
) AS Sqlvars
WHERE job.pcreation_date BETWEEN "2013-10-02 00:00:00" AND "2013-10-02 23:59:59"
GROUP BY task_template.puid,
        task_template.ptemlate_name,
        "start"
ORDER BY task_template.ptemlate_name, 
            "start";
```

Note that you do have further potential issues with the fields returned due to how you are grouping rows. For example if there are multiple values of _job.pcreation_date_ for a value of puid / ptemlate_name then which one is used is not determined.